# Is there a limit on the size of a chart?

Tags: excel

I have a table that has been growing in size since the start of 2021.
This table is then generating a chart, the chart width is calculated to make sure it'd wide enough so you can read the data with `ActiveChart.Parent.Width = (lastrow - 2) * 20`.

Currently the `?selection.width` is 85700.

Now something strange has happened.

[image]

The x-axis has compressed the end.
There is a total of three charts on the sheet. These two have i made smaller, `?selection.width` is 84651 and 84606, but the number of data points is still the same.
So making the chart smaller spaces out the data points.

[image]

I realize that I could just make sure the width is always keep the width 84000 but that will bunch up the values in the chart over time.
Anyone know of a way to solve this or if this is some setting or any solution? Sorry for the wideness of the question but I'm looking for a solution to a bug(?) in Excel

Comment: Is it really necessary to show all data all the time? Perhaps you could add a timeline slicer to ease filtering the period shown on the chart?

Comment: @jkpieterse Interesting idea. I was hoping that I didn't have to cut off the data, but having a slicer is a good trade off. I'll think about this. Thank you!